# FastLane: is there a way to generate android/iOS build from a remote branch in bitbucket?

Tags: android, ios, jenkins, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

I am planning to use FastLane instead of Jenkins, as FastLane focuses mainly on Android and iOS projects.

I couldn't find any documentation in FastLane to generate Android/iOS builds (apk or archives) from a remote branch in BitBucket.

Their documentation specifies how to make a build from the project present in our system. I wanted to generate a build without importing that project remotely.

Is there a way in FastLane to generate android/iOS build from a remote branch in bitbucket?

Comment: AFAIK, no, there is not a way to do it. So we used both Jenkins and Fastlane. First, we pulled the repository from a remote branch with a Jenkins pipeline. After that, we triggered a new pipeline for Fastlane scripts to build and upload to PlayStore and AppStore.